# generate java domain objects from database table

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, domain-driven-design

may i know in eclipse, is there any feature that will auto generate domain objects with all table relationship properly mapped in class?

can provide me with some reference articles on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(Java)) to accomplish this

This [plugin set for Eclipse](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html) called Hibernate Tools for Eclipse and ANT will do most of the work for you.

In particular it will do Reverse Engineering: The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is a database reverse engineering tool that can generate domain model classes and Hibernate mapping files, annotated EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation or even an entire JBoss Seam application in seconds!

Answer (score 8):

**Telosys code generator** does this kind of job.
It's an **Eclipse plugin**, it uses the database schema to create a light model
that is used to generate the Java code.

There are some predefined templates available on GitHub (for JPA, POJO, Documentation, Spring MVC, etc )

See http://www.telosys.org

and http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

Templates : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3

Articles about code generation with Telosys :

- https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/
- https://dzone.com/articles/telosys-a-code-generation-tool-by-laurent-guerin

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hibernate Tools 3.0.0.GA either via Eclipse or ANT to auto-generate your hibernate domain entities directly from your database tables.

See tutorial here :
http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.0.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you i.e to create  auto generate domain objects with all table relationship properly mapped in class ...Try ***Dal4j*** yes you can find it in **[sourceforge.net/p/dal4j/wiki/](http://sourceforge.net/p/dal4j/wiki/)** DAL4j is a Command Line and Framework tool that can be used to reverse engineer a MySQL or SQLServer database schema into a set of JPA Entity Beans.

DAL4j can be useful for scenarios where there is an existing database schema but a technology other that JPA is used by applications to interact with the database. DAL4j can provide an easy way to migrate your code base from other technologies such as JDBC or Hibernate to JPA.

The beans generated can be 1 or two types: Simple or Framework. Simple beans are standard pojo classes managed by your application using JPA semantics. Framework generated pojos use the DAL4j framework DAO generic to simplify CRUD operations.

DAL4j provides optional hooks to allow you integrate encryption/decryption of data fields that must be encrypted in the database.

Last, DAL4j provides a set of Generic classes that can be used to simplify creation of Session Beans which perform CRUD operations using generated Entities.

I think you will find this article feasible....

Answer (score 0):

You want an  [object relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) of which Hibernate is the most popular for Java.  The hibernate tools are typically better for taking annotated classes and using them to generate a schema, as opposed to vice versa, which is what you sound like you're doing.  I suspect you'll be doing a lot of hand-annotating if you're working with a legacy DB schema.

Comment: Reverse Engineering: The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is a database reverse engineering tool that can generate domain model classes and Hibernate mapping files, annotated EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation or even an entire JBoss Seam application in seconds! https://www.hibernate.org/255.html

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic the link is broken; do you have the updated link? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use grails, you can generate domain objects with GRAG http://sourceforge.net/projects/grag

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse for java development, but when it comes to generating domain entities I use Net beans.

Create an EJB module, and then right click and generate entities.
You need to set up the database also you can select the tables you want visually.

Regards
Lyju

Answer (score 0):

It feels like another rather common question that people always run into.

The link below links to a blog detailed enough for me to learn how to generate entities from database schema the first time.
http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-create-java-classes-from-tables.html

Just in case, the following link refers to eclipse help page. This link should never expire:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm

I downloaded JBoss and failed to understand how it works. I think the plugin that I used is Hibernate Tools but I am not sure as I did not install any new plugin for this purpose. I am using Eclipse Luna for EE.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got so tired of manually coding this kind of stuff so I made a tool to generate models, dao, and dao implementation from a schema.  It's oriented towards spring boot and only tested on MySQL, but for those that don't want to use Hibernate and just want to work with jdbc/sql and JdbcTemplate, or just want POJOs with getter/setters generated for tables, then this could perhaps be something to kick off the coding.

Called Jassd (Java Automated Spring Source-code for Databases generator), I'm "jazzed" to introduce this tool: https://github.com/aforslund/jassd